# algebraic $1$-forms vs analytic $1$-forms

Tags: algebraic-geometry, differential-geometry, differential-forms

First let's fix some definitions:

**Definitions:**

- *Complex manifold (of dimension n)*: Is a locally ringed space $(X,\mathscr F)$, where there is an open cover $\bigcup_{i\in I} U_i=X$ such that $(U_i,\mathscr F_{X|U})\cong (V, \mathscr O_V)$ (as locally ringed spaces). Here $V\subseteq\mathbb C^n$ is an open set and  $\mathscr O_V$ is the sheaf of holomorphic functions. This definition is equivalent to the usual "chart definition".
- *Complex Variety (of dimension n)*: Is a locally ringed space $(X,\mathscr G)$, where there is an open cover $\bigcup_{i\in I} U_i=X$ such that $(U_i,\mathscr G_{X|U})\cong (V, \mathcal O_V)$. Here $V\subseteq\mathbb C^n$ is an open set and  $\mathcal O_V$ is the sheaf of regular functions.
- *Holomorphic $1$-form on a manifold*: Is a holomorphic section of the cotangent bundle. In particular a global holomorphic form  can be written as $\omega= fdz$ where $f\in\mathscr F(X)$
- *Algebraic $1$-form on a variety*:  If $A$ is a $k$-algebra, one defines [the Kahler module of differentials](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K%C3%A4hler_differential) $\Omega_{A/k}$. Then the $\mathcal O_X$-module of algebraic differentials on $X$ is the sheaf $$\Omega^1_X(U):=\Omega_{\mathcal O_X(U)/\mathbb C}$$
  An element of $\Omega^1_X(X)$ is a global algebraic $1$-form.
- *Meromorphic $1$-form on a manifold*: Is a meromorphic section of the cotangent bundle. In particular a global meromorphic form  can be written as $\omega= fdz$ where $f$ is meromorphic.

**My questions:**

1. Clearly an algebraic $1$-form is also an holomorphic $1$-form, but the converse doesn't hold. Are there some particular cases where every holomorphic $1$-form  is also algebraic?
2. What are the algebraic correspondents of meromorphic $1$-forms? Maybe one should define the sheaf
   $$\mathcal M(U):= \Omega_{\mathbb C(X)/\mathbb C}$$
   where $\mathbb C(X)$ is the field of rational functions.

Comment: For (1), check out Serre's GAGA theorem. If your variety is projective then anything holomorphic is actually algebraic.

Comment: The algebraic counterpart of meromorphic 1-forms are elements of the stalk of the sheaf of algebraic 1-forms at the generic point.